# Expression Engine entry_id Parse

Tags: expressionengine, author

Hey Everyone I am having a huge problem :

I have this Line :

```
{exp:entries:ids_assigned_to_me tag="idont" channel="proiecte" field="clienti"}
```

Which outputs me  some entry ids

and i can put it There at the entry_id:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="proiecte" entry_id=" HERE "  }
```

`{content}
 {/exp:channel:entries}`

I tryied and search for hours over forums and stuff, but variable, snippets and embeding and stuff doesen't seemed to work out. Any Ideas ? about Inward Parse or something ?

Also tried php but didn't worked out :((

Comment: Try asking over on http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You're using the [entries add-on](https://objectivehtml.com/entries) and by the looks of it you're using the single tag method. It's not clear from the documentation, but I think as you're specifying a single tag, it's outputting the IDs, but if you use it as a tag pair (as other examples in the documentation show) and this piece of documentation hints at: "If no entries are assigned the logged in member, the no_results conditional is returned.".

So first try

```
{exp:entries:ids_assigned_to_me tag="idont" channel="proiecte" field="clienti"}
    {content}
{/exp:entries:ids_assigned_to_me}
```

...all by itself without any {exp:channel:entries} tags. No idea what "tag" parameter is doing in there.

If that doesn't work and that method doesn't support a tag pair, then you'll need to do as an embed across 2 templates:

1st template:

```
{embed=template-group/second-template entry_ids="{exp:entries:ids_assigned_to_me tag="idont" channel="proiecte" field="clienti"}"}
```

2nd template:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="proiecte" entry_id="{embed:entry_ids}"}
    {content}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```